# Spring Boot Elasticearch Repository - @Id with Class instead of @Id with String

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-repositories

Should be simple, but I find no way to solve this issue. I have a repository of `Profile` with a class @Id `User` with interface:

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Profile, User> {
```

The Profile is:

```
public class Profile {
    @Id
    private User user;
    [... plus getters, setters, constructors]
```

The User is:

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String role;
    [... plus getters, setters, constructors]
```

No problem saving the Profile (as you can see ElasticSearch puts a String representation of the user):

```
      "_id": "User(id=TestID, role=TestRole)",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "_class": "com.example.model.Profile",
                "user": {
                    "id": "TestID",
                    "role": "TestRole"
                },
```

But after that I can't retrieve any of the profiles.
If I do any of the following:

```
profileRepository.findAll();
profileRepository.customFindByIdRole("TestID", "TestRole");
profileRepository.findById(new User("TestID", "TestRole"));
```

I always get:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.example.model.User]
```

Note: customFindByIdRole is implemented this way:

```
@Query("{\"query\": { \"bool\": { \"must\": [ { \"match\": { \"user.id\": \"?0\" } }, { \"match\": { \"user.role\": \"?1\" } } ] } }}")
Profile customFindByIdRole(String id, String role);
```

Also please note that if I add any of the Spring JPA dependencies a lot is being broken, so I'm not sure I can rely on @Embedded @IdClass etc.